# Dictionaries and checkboxes - uninitialised issue

Tags: c#

The code below is trying to initialize the checkboxes in a dialogue box by setting them to checked or unchecked based on a saved value retrieved from `Settings.GetOption()`. However the checkboxes are still uninitialized after this code runs and I think it's because when referring to `checkbox.Key` it is a copy of the object instead of a reference. How can I make it a reference so that the code works properly?

```
Dictionary<CheckBox, string> checkboxes = new Dictionary<CheckBox, string>() {
            { CheckEnableHotkeys, "EnableHotkeys" },
            { CheckMinimizePlayback, "MinimizeOnPlayback" },
            { CheckMinimizeRecording, "MinimizeOnRecord" },
            { CheckLoopPlayback, "LoopPlayback" },
            { CheckJitterMode, "JitterMode" }
        };


foreach (KeyValuePair<CheckBox, string> checkbox in checkboxes)
            checkbox.Key.Checked = Settings.GetOption(checkbox.Value) == 1;
```

**EDIT: The problem is that the checkboxes are still all unchecked even after the code runs and I'm not completely sure why. **

Comment: Are you sure that Settings.GetOption() is returning 1? I highly doubt it's some kind of copy.

Comment: Why do you think it's a copy?

Comment: "it's not working" - What exactly *is* it doing?

Comment: `checkbox.Key` has `CheckBox` type, which is a reference by definition. Better explain, what's the problem exactly.

Comment: @Dennis: Actually, we cannot be sure about that, as the OP has not given away yet what `CheckBox` type he or she is using - WinForms? WPF? A custom `struct` of a custom GUI framework?

Comment: I'm using the framework that comes by default with VSExpress 2012 for C#.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: probability of custom `struct CheckBox` is near zero. `CheckBox`es in WPF or WinForms are reference types.

Comment: Use the debugger to find out what `Settings.GetOption(checkbox.Value)` returns at runtime.

Comment: @Ryan: VS Express 2012 does not come with any UI frameworks of its own. The .NET Framework that VS Express 2012 for C# serves as an IDE for, however, does include several UI frameworks - according to MSDN, there are (at least) 3 distinct classes called `CheckBox` from three different UI frameworks.

Comment: @Dennis: Checkboxes in WPF, WinForms etc. are indeed reference types, and at the same time we have an OP absolutely convinced that his or her `CheckBox` is copied rather than referenced. Hence, there are reasons for each of the options, and only the OP can provide more insight into what is going on there.

Comment: Whenever someone suspects that a copy of some object is implicitly being made this is usually not the case. It is very non-trivial to clone objects. You can't just clone a CheckBox object and expect WPF-internal invariants to still hold. For that reason, cloning is not generally possible. There is just no general mechanism to do it.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed the problem, apparently it was a problem with saving the values of the input boxes.